# List all user-created enums in Postgres for a particular database

Tags: postgresql, enums

There are dozens of tables in a database with numerous fields using user-defined enumerations. Is there a simple way to list all user-defined enumeration types for a particular database (all enums used in all tables in that database)?

Some of them that exists are things like `weekday`, `user_type`, etc... but I don't want to look for them manually.

I know if I have one, I can enumerate all possible values with something like `select enum_range(enum_first(null::weekday),null::weekday)`, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7):

[Gus](http://www.gbonfant.com/blog/list-postgres-enums) has the answer.

`SELECT pg_type.typname AS enum_type, pg_enum.enumlabel AS enmu_label FROM pg_type JOIN pg_enum ON pg_enum.enumtypid = pg_type.oid;`